# Calulator--click digits and display in the textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I want to practice a simple calculator. I am in the very first step.
[image: calculator]

If we click keys, it is supposed to display a number. For example, clicking 1, then 2, then 3, it will display "123" in the text box. Now it is not working. Please see [the demo in jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/36AwV/)

I used a variable 'inputVal' to collect digits. It is initialized as empty. Then assign it to the text box.

```
var inputVal ="";
// Add onclick event to all the keys and perform operations
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i].onclick = function (e) {
       var input = document.querySelector('.keys');
       inputVal += input.innerHTML;
    }
} 
document.getElementsByClassName("window").item(0).innerHTML=inputVal;
```

I need to correct my code. By the way, if I click "." which is a decimal number, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler should be modifying the text box. Right now, you set the value of the text field, but you don't update it in response to click events!

Try this:

```
var keys = document.querySelectorAll('.keys span');
var textField = document.getElementsByClassName("window").item(0);
var operators = ['+', '-', 'x', '÷'];

// Add onclick event to all the keys and perform operations
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i].onclick = function (e) {
        // `this` is always set to the target element
        textField.innerHTML += this.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

See <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36AwV/3/)</kbd>.

Update:

To exclude keys, you can do this:

```
var exclude = ['0', 'C'];
// Add onclick event to all the keys and perform operations
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i].onclick = function (e) {
        var keyVal = this.innerHTML;
        if (exclude.indexOf(keyVal) >= 0) return;
        // `this` is always set to the target element
        textField.innerHTML += keyVal;

    }
}
```

Comment: With a simple `if` statement … or by excluding those from the elements the handler is bound to in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you fiddle working:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/5B649/1/)

I changed this:

```
keys[i].onclick = function(e) {
    inputVal += e.target.innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByClassName("window").item(0).innerHTML = inputVal; 
}
```

`function( e )` so you are going to know the target of your click `e.target.innerHTML`